React MUI Datagrid cell update trigger
I'm using MUI's DataGrid component and trying to update the backend when a cell value is edited. However, I'm running into issues where the cell value sometimes reverts or the onCellEditCommit event isn't triggered properly. I want to capture the id, field (column name), and the new value when a cell is edited.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import axios from 'axios';

const dropdownColumns = ['Action Status', 'Process Update'];

const getOptionsForColumn = (column) => {
  if (column === 'Action Status') {
    return ['Pending', 'Scheduled', 'Updated', 'Closed'];
  }
  return [];
};

const MyDataGrid = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch initial data (mocked for this example)
    setRows([
      { id: 1, 'Action Status': 'Pending', 'Process Update': 'In Progress' },
      { id: 2, 'Action Status': 'Scheduled', 'Process Update': 'Completed' },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleCellEditCommit = async (params) => {
    try {
      const { id, field, value } = params;

      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/update', {
        component: id,
        column: field,
        value,
      });

      console.log('Updated:', { id, field, value });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating cell value:', error);
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'Action Status',
      headerName: 'Action Status',
      editable: true,
      type: 'singleSelect',
      valueOptions: getOptionsForColumn('Action Status'),
    },
    {
      field: 'Process Update',
      headerName: 'Process Update',
      editable: true,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        onCellEditCommit={handleCellEditCommit}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyDataGrid;


Issue:
Sometimes when I edit a cell, the value reverts to its original state or the onCellEditCommit event isn't triggered. How can I ensure that the event is consistently triggered, and the cell values are updated properly?
Expected Output:
I expect the cell to remain updated after editing, and the backend API to be called with the correct id, field, and value.
Additional Notes:
I've tried using processRowUpdate, onCellEditStop, etc., but I still encounter issues.
Any guidance on properly handling cell edits in DataGrid would be appreciated.

i also used processRowUpdate. from which i got 2 rows updated and old row data. and i use this code to get those { id, field, value }
const id = newRow.Component;
let field = null;
let value = null;
for (const key in newRow) {
if (newRow[key] !== oldRow[key]) {
field = key;
value = newRow[key];
break; // Stop after finding the first difference
}
}
but since i use single select, its updating but the dropdown menu is not closing , its stays open or active(like a 3d box)
